# Javascript event on keypress, but after the character has been entered

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard

So I'm doing character counting on a text field. I need to update the character count on keypress (not keyup). The issue is that with jquery's `.keydown()` method, it refreshes the counter before the character is entered, so the counter is always 1 keypress behind the actual count. How can I get the count to change on keypress, but wait for the character to be entered?

Thanks!

Comment: sounds like you should use `keyup`, it does what you want.

Comment: On key up, isn't the letter guaranteed to be entered? I don't see how you could be off by one...

Comment: Why *not* keyup? It's exactly what you want in this scenario.

Comment: Keydown feels more responsive. Keyup is too easy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`setTimeout` seems to work here:

```
$('input').keydown(function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
        var text = $this.val();
        console.log(text.length);
    }, 0);
});
```

Answer (score 9):

Use [`.keyup()`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) instead. It's triggered when the key is released, so the counter will increment then.

From the documentation:

> The keyup event is sent to an element when the user releases a key on
>   the keyboard. It can be attached to any element, but the event is only
>   sent to the element that has the focus.

You use it in the same way you would any other event:

```
$('input').keyup(function(e) {
    var text = $(this).val();
    console.log(text.length);
});
```

Make sure to count the number of characters in the text box (as in the example above), **not the number of keys pressed**. For example, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> would result in two extra characters counted, but none actually entered into the input.

---

If you're using jQuery 1.7+, use `.on()`:

```
$('input').on('keyup', function(e) {
    // Do your magic
});
```

Comment: I would highly recommend that you check the actual value of the `Input` or `TextArea`, as [CTRL]+[C] will most likely be more than a single character.

Comment: @Erik Thank you for that. I personally always count the number of characters in the input, but I've edited my answer to make it clear that's what you _should_ do.

Comment: Why is .on('keyup') superior to .keyup()?

Comment: It's not necessarily superior, but is the recommended way to handle events in jQuery versions above 1.7 (inclusive). Either way is acceptable, however it should be noted that `.on()` supports event delegation if a third argument is used.

Answer (score 2):

A simple example:

```
var MAX_CHARACTERS = 60;
$('textarea').bind('keyup keydown', function() {
    var $element = $(this);
    if($element.val().length > MAX_CHARACTERS) {
        $element.val($element.val().substring(0, MAX_CHARACTERS));
    }
    $('.counter').val(MAX_CHARACTERS - $element.val().length);
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/yzDU7/)